# How to click on the class which contains particular text using Selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriver, webdriverwait

```
<h3 _ngcontent-ydk-c51="" matline="" class="mat-line">Text1</h3>

<h3 _ngcontent-ydk-c51="" matline="" class="mat-line">Text2</h3>
```

There are many links with class ="mat-line", but i want to click on link which contains **Text1**, how to do it ?

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Comment: I am using C# for programming.

Answer (score 1):

To click on the element with text as **Text1** you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the `elementToBeClickable()` (Java) / `element_to_be_clickable()` (Python) and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *Java* and `xpath`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//h3[@class='mat-line' and text()='Text1']"))).click();
  ```
- Using *Python* and `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//h3[@class='mat-line' and contains(., 'Text1')]"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: Using *Python* client you have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Answer (score 0):

To get an h3 class of mat-line with text Text1 try the following xpath.

```
//h3[contains(text(), "Text1") and @class="mat-line"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Found these two xpath working for Selenium with C#

```
"//h3[contains(text(),'Text1')]"

"//*[@class='mat-line'][.='Text1']"
```